# Bit.dev unable to add 2 components with the same ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bit.dev

To manage my severals `react` components I decide to use [bit](https://bit.dev/). Then I add a component `loginForm` that is a directory with this structure:

```
├── loginForm
│   ├── loginForm.scss
│   └── loginForm.tsx
```

I use for that the cli command `add`:

```sh
bit add ./loginForm/*
```

But I get this error that I don't really understand:

> unable to add 2 components with the same ID: login-form/login-form

As someone an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit uses glob patterns to "find" files and create a set distinct `add` command, each to a set of files. So in this case, the use of a wildcard (`*`) in a folder with two files, returned 2 files to the `bit add` command to iterate over.

i.e. the syntax in the question is a "snippet" to run:

```
$ bit add loginForm/loginForm.tsx
$ bit add loginForm/loginForm.scss
```

With these two commands, Bit's default behavior is taking the file name to be tracked, and use it as the component name. So both cases it's `login-form`. Bit does not allow having two components with identical IDs.

To have Bit track the entire folder as a component you can omit the wildcard and run:

```
$ bit add ./loginForm
```

This way you tell Bit to track the entire directory as a single component, not tracking each individual file as a component.

It's also possible to group the results of a glob pattern to a single component using the `--id` option. This tells Bit to take all files found in the glob pattern and instead of running "many" `bit add` (for each file/directory), it runs a single one with a set component ID. For example:

```
$ bit add ./loginForm/* --id login-form
```

This way it tells Bit to add all files in the `./loginForm` directory to be tracked by a single component instance. Using the `--id` option you can also add files to that component even after it was tracked, as it tells Bit to `add` files to the mentioned component ID.

If you have several folders containing files and you want each folder to be a component and use a single command, then you can use the glob pattern.

```
├── LoginForm
│   ├── LoginForm.scss
│   └── LoginForm.tsx
└── LogoutForm
    ├── LogoutForm.scss
    └── LogoutForm.tsx
```

You could run:

```
$ bit add ./*
```

To have the glob pattern give `bit add` the two folders to track.

Comment: Thank you for this very precise and interesting answer. It's work great! You deserve the bounty ;)

Comment: it's not about the bounty, it's about helping more people that find your question! I've added a note about the `--id` option that can help resolve the issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

the only possible solution for me looks like to change one filename e.g.

```
├─loginForm
│  │  loginForm.tsx
│  │  loginForm.style.scss
```

Comment: Mmmh well it seems a little too radical

Comment: I agree with Matt.

Comment: @Kundan agree with him so much that you're stealing his answer? :/

Comment: I'm not stealing. I already answered before him. But I answered using a link. So I made a change and answered again without link. But if you think I'm stealing your answer then I'm ready to delete it.

Comment: I even have link to the post from where I gathered information.

Comment: @johannchopin You should not talk to somebody like that even after knowing the truth that I had answered the question first. Just because I used a link before and afterwards I made a edit to write that link content here doesn't mean that I have stole somebody's content

Comment: @johannchopin for me it looks also a bad solution. At my client we have same file structure. Multiple files with same name but different extensions. I would also not rename all. But in case of bit it looks like.